# PHP: $argv variable screws up environmental variables in DB connection

Tags: php, argv

I have a weird problem.
I am "firing" a PHP page (page 2) from within another PHP page (page 1) by using exec, which sends a $argv variable to page 2.

The issue is, the DB connection on page 2 breaks because the $argv variable messes my environment variables for the DB connection ($_ENV['DB_USER'] and $_ENV['DB_PW']).
I get an error like the password is incorrect ([1045] Access denied for user...).
It only happens if I call page 2 using the exec command on page 1, otherwise the connection works fine.

If I comment out the DB connection, the $argv[1] (ID I need) is passed to page 2 without issues.

It works fine if the DB connection has hardcoded values for user and pass.

I've tested a lot, and am positive $argv is screwing up my environmental variables.

I tried encasing the variable for the on page 1 in escapeshellarg, but no difference.

Does anyone have any ideas why?

By the way, I don't want to use includes or cUrl to run page 2.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

## PAGE 1:

```
$doc_id = "123";
$doc_id = escapeshellarg($doc_id);

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
exec('php '.$path.'/dashboard/test/argv-2.php '.        
$doc_id .' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

## PAGE 2

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable(__DIR__ . '/../../../../'); //root
$dotenv->load();


$tz_sync = (new DateTime('now', new  DateTimeZone('America/New_York')))->format('P');

$db = new     PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx_main;charset=utf8mb4',             
$_ENV['DB_USER'], $_ENV['DB_PW']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->exec("SET time_zone='$tz_sync';");


$doc_id = $argv[1]; 

//get doc title
$rowDocTitle = getDocTitle($db,$doc_id);
$doc_title = $rowDocTitle['doc_title'];


//email
$tox = 'xyzxyz@xxxxxx.com';
$subjectx = 'Doc title';
$messagex = "Doc title: " . $doc_title . "\n\n";
$headersx = 'From: xxxx@xxxxxx.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: xxxx@xxxxxx.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($tox, $subjectx, $messagex, $headersx);
```

Comment: Where are these environment variables defined and for which profile?

Comment: I have the environment variables in a file .env. 
I use the script at github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv to access them.

Comment: So is the _page 2_ script using that? Please [edit] your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you sure you need `exec` to interact with other PHP page/script?

Comment: Yes, I need to use exec. Page 2 has to be decoupled from page 1.

Comment: Have you displayed the contents of `$_ENV` in the second process?  If the variables are actually in the environment, then they should be inherited.  If you're actually talking about a configuration file, then you need to use `phpdotenv` in the second script as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly where and how you're using `phpdotenv`

Comment: $_ENV and the db connection works fine if I don't pass $argv to page 2.
I've tested it thoroughly.
For example, if I use $doc_id = "123"; on page 2, everything works fine.

Comment: This sounds like a bug with `phpdotenv` then. If you can construct a minimal reproduction (keep it super simple), [raise an issue](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/issues)

Comment: The answer below, by Damien Monk, fixed the issue. Thank you all.